# Every Time I create a new angular project it gives me 5k commits

Tags: angular, git, github, angular-cli

I haven't initialized git yet in this project but everytime I create a new angular
project through angular cli , it gives me 5k commits on vscode.I want there to be no commits so
I can initialize a new git repository and push all the data there.I have created a new repo and I
want to attach that with my code.

[image]

Comment: use a .gitignore file

Comment: Those are not commits - those are files that **can be added** to a commit. It seems like you created made initialized a git repository in your home directory and it shows all files there.

Comment: still using a gitignore

Comment: Why/what are all those junk-GUID-name files in the ROOT of the project? **Where did the files come from, what what is their purpose?** Inspecting the content may be useful.. Are they temp files? If so, can they be deleted and/or moved out-of-the-project (if local/temp artifacts)? If not, can they be placed in a grouped folder? It's much easier/cleaner to git-ignore a folder and use a reverse ignore or ignore based on GUID-match. Plus, I'd get irritated if having to "see" those files in my WC. *tldr; fix the source of the problem.*

Comment: @sagat This is a tooling issue. Nothing to git-ignore without proper cleanup first (perhaps the ideal approach is to delete this junk files? to change a temp path? to..?).

Comment: @AbdulRehman That's the _branch_ the WC is on. These files might be in a commit (see git status, eg). However, are they 5k _separate commits_ (?!?) or 5k _files_ committed (?) or are they a bunch of not tracked (?) files.. my _suspicion_ is it is a problem identifying a Temp Path.

Comment: I have initialized so many angular projects with angular cli and vs code i cant count. And with a proper gitignore I never had this kind of issue.

Comment: @sagat even if using . gitignore removes all these files still why is there a " master* " on the bottom left of the screenshot

Comment: @AbdulRehman The WC branch and ignored files are not related. The "*" says the WC is dirty. In this case the "U" likely indicates these are new files, probably added with `git add .` (which I don't recommended in general). If they are not in a commit, and are junk files, merely delete them. For git-ignore to be effective, the files must be _not tracked_ (git-ignore only applies to files that are no tracked; if a file is already staged or added the file is not ignored). If these are new files, they can be reset. If the files really are _updates_, then.. again, identify the content/source first.

Comment: pls share ur project structure with parent and subfolders, also which commands did u execute?

Comment: Anyway, I suspect that the Temp Path settings are either set or defaulting to the working directory..

Comment: @sagat i just went to desktop and wrote ng new projectName

Comment: @user2864740 i have other projects on desktop aswell , none of which have had this problem

Comment: Sounds like you might have put it inside another repo?